# Incluir Libreria Manualmente Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

Que tal chicos, necesito agregar la librería FPDF a un proyecto que he realizado en Laravel 5, el proyecto se encuentra en producción en un servidor desde el que solo tengo acceso por FTP, ¿de que forma puedo incluir dicha librería manualmente, a mi proyecto?, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tener acceso solo FTP complica mucho las cosas a la hora de incluir librerías, actualizarlas, etc. Tengo una web con la misma situación, sino conectas muchas cosas (nuevas librerías), aunque hacer cambios sea incómodo, se lleva, con más trabajo. Si necesitas más librerías, actualizar dependencias, etc. es mejor cambiar el hosting porque el trabajo va a ser una locura y te lo puedes cargar todo con cierta facilidad.
Para la actualización por FTP vas a tener que **usar Git**, para el proceso, aunque sea indirectamente. Si no lo has manejado antes, tranquilo que solo van a ser comandos básicos.

Bueno al lío:

1. Hacer copia de todo.
   Guarda 2 copias locales. Una de seguridad, para restaurar el sistema y la otra la vas a actualizar, instalando la librería, esta va a ser la copia de desarrollo.
2. Debes tener la copia de desarrollo bajo control de versiones. Hacer un commit de todo. Así veras todo lo que cambia cuando instalas la librería.
3. Instalada la librería y verificado que funciona en tu copia de desarrollo.
4. Hay que subir los archivos nuevos / modificados. Haz un **diff**, del repositorio. Tendrás que subir la librería, las dependencias, el fichero de configuración de providers, los ficheros donde el autoload mapea las clases... en fin el **diff**, te lo dirá, son unos cuantos.
5. Probar en producción.

Si, no usaste Git antes, el proceso es:

1. Instalar Git
2. Abrir la consola e ir al directorio con la copia de desarrollo. Algo como cd c:\php\laravel\mi_web
3. Iniciar el repositorio local: **git init**
4. Añadir todos los archivos: **git commit --all -m 'inicio repo'**
5. Realizada la instalación, pruebas, etc. Ver cambios: **git status**
   (Todo lo que hay en rojo hay que subirlo: ficheros y los directorios completos)
6. Subir todo por FTP